# how do you format numbers in vector without having extra spaces and quotes around the numbers

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
dput(yy)
c(97.1433841613379, 1102.1208262592, 32.5418522860492, 217.694780086999, 
1306.31759309228, 202.18335752298, 22.8301149425287)
```

I need to only keep 2 decimal points and I am doing this to get rid of additional decimal points:

```
yy<-format(yy, digits=1)
```

When I do dput(yy), I get additional spaces in front of the my values as this:

```
dput(yy)
c("  97.14", "1102.12", "  32.54", " 217.69", "1306.32", " 202.18", 
"  22.83")
```

Is there an easy way to format the numbers without inserting extra space and quotes around the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `?sprintf` (it use the same syntax like `sprintf` in C):

```
x <- c(97.1433841613379, 1102.1208262592, 32.5418522860492, 217.694780086999, 1306.31759309228, 202.18335752298, 22.8301149425287)
sprintf("%.2f", x)
# [1] "97.14"   "1102.12" "32.54"   "217.69"  "1306.32" "202.18"  "22.83"
```

EDIT:
Or do you look for `?round`?

```
round(x, digits=2)
# [1]   97.14 1102.12   32.54  217.69 1306.32  202.18   22.83
```

Comment: there are quotes around the numbers, there needs to be no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything as numbers then use `round(x, 2)`, however that will change a number like `1.5000002` to `1.5` rather than `1.50` that you could get with `format` or `sprintf`.